# Applying to all figcaption tags

Tags: css

Unlike img/h/p and some other tags, I noticed I can't create a css for all figcaptions in a single block.
Currently I defined a block per figcaption but I'm afraid I missed some potential figcaption:

```
.wp-block-embed figcaption {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.wp-block-image figcaption {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: What's "a single block"? If you want to target all figcaptions, why not just use the selector `figcaption`? You could also use the starts with selector, `[class^='wp-block-'] figcaption`. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qod3wxhf/

Comment: Thank you. the 'starts with' is a good solution! I've tried using `figcaption` solely but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the CSS [begins with attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), `^`:

```
[class^='wp-block-'] figcaption
```

```css
[class^='wp-block-'] figcaption {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-block-embed">
  <figure><img src="">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
<div class="wp-block-image">
  <figure><img src="">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <figure><img src="">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
<div>
  <figure><img src="">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```